# Projector with Build-in Desktop PC

Tags: projector

I'm looking for a 1080P capable projector that is also a PC (built-in).

Instead of dedicating a separate computer (to always be hooked up to a projector in the meeting room), it would be nice if I could find a projector that could do remote desktop connections (RDP) to various computers on our LAN, without being hooked up to a separate PC.

This would allow each presenter to present from their own workstation from within the meeting-room, and if the projector is wifi capable, the only cable needed (to be plugged into the projector) is the power cable alone.

It would be even extra cool if I could install Ubuntu Linux 16.04.3 as the operating system and use Remmina Remote Desktop Client to facilitate the RDP connections to the various workstations.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more easily solve your problem if you divide it in 2 devices. Get any common projector that solves your presentation needs, but with an HDMI input.

With that get an Intel compute stick or a raspberry pi with Wi-Fi, put your OS on that and get remmina running from the network.